# Querying data from firebase using if else

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have retrieved data from my firestore storage using this code:

```
class User {
  bool isActive;
  String databaseID;
  String email;
  
  User() {
    this.isActive = '';
    this.databaseID = '';
    this.email = '';
  }
  toJson() {
    return {
      'isActive': this.isActive,
      "databaseID": this.databaseID,
      "email": this.email,
      "
    };
  }

  fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.isActive = json['isActive'];
    this.databaseID = json["databaseID"];
    this.email = json["email"];
      });
    }
  }
```

The data consists of databaseID, email address and isActive method which determines if a user is active or not. This isActive is a boolean value in the database with true and false methods.
Now I want to write a query where if isActive is false it should print "User is NOT active" else it should print User is active. I have written this code but it is giving error

```
    try {
    // get isActive if available
      bool isActive = this.isActive;

      if (isActive == false) {
        return false;
      }

      else {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please share what error you are getting

Comment: Invalid reference to 'this' expression

Comment: how is getIsActive being called?
It seems isActive is not in the scope of getIsActive.

Comment: can you share any simple way? I am actually using previously available code

Comment: where are you calling `getIsActive()`? Also this has nothing to do with node or javascript

Comment: sorry that function is not created. I updated the code. Please check

Comment: @ajay131 I mean the whole code where is it getting called? In a seperate class?

Comment: yes outside the user class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the class to the following:

```
class User {
  bool isActive;
  String databaseID;
  String email;
  
  User() {
    this.isActive = true;
    this.databaseID = '';
    this.email = '';
  }
  toJson() {
    return {
      'isActive': this.isActive,
      "databaseID": this.databaseID,
      "email": this.email,
    };
  }

  fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.isActive = json['isActive'];
    this.databaseID = json["databaseID"];
    this.email = json["email"];
      }
    }
```

`isActive` is of type `bool` so you should either assign `true` or `false` not `string`. Then to assign `isActive` to a variable you have to create an instance of class `User`:

```
User user = new User();
user.isActive = false;
bool isActive = user.isActive;
```

Comment: Yes. After that how to query based on if else?

Comment: `if (isActive == false) {
        return false;
      }

      else {
        return true;
      }`

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: on this line ```bool isActive = user.isActive;``` I am getting "Instance member 'isActive' can't be accessed using static access"

Comment: can you please share the complete code. I am really having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219797/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-ajay131).